# Matlab equivalent code for file

Tags: string, matlab, file

Can I replace `~files(i).isdir` for `~isdir('files(i)')`?

What does the `.` do in the code? Is it like an abbreviation of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that "files" is an array of structures, and isdir is a variable under the structure  (read MATLAB documentation for further informations about structures) at position i, so you can't replace the instruction with the function-like one.